# Next-Auth Field 'identifier' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, next.js, next-auth

I am setting up next-auth for my app and trying to add login with email. I used mysql schemas from next-auth documentation and one of them is verification_requests:

```
CREATE TABLE verification_requests
  (
    id         INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    identifier VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    token      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    expires    TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
    updated_at TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );
```

When I try to login with email, it is giving following error:
**Field 'identifier' doesn't have a default value** for following query:

```
INSERT INTO `verification_requests`(`id`, `identifier`, `token`, `expires`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, '1db565ee611f2ed6c5ec0dacd79ac1fd3ffb860e1a249cfc7320b5e8381c0201', '2021-01-12 03:27:31.357', DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
```

I am getting this error because next-auth is trying to insert info verification_requests table but since the schema doesn't have default value for field identifier, it is throwing error. I couldn't find any thing mentioned about what kind of default value we need to declare in mysql schema for the Identifier field. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You just mentioned the identifier field to be not null. Set a default value for the 'identifier' column. Understand that u r using `not null` and it means u should not leave ur field empty.

Comment: I know that `not null` means I cannot leave it null when inserting data and the insert query is from next auth itself. The field `identifier` in that table must have some meaning to next-auth which confused me what sort of value can be default for it, and I could not find anything about it in the next-auth documentation.

Comment: I don't know about next-auth(just hearing this). But i know MySQL enough to answer this. Apply a default value to the identifier column from the database. Use `ALTER TABLE verification_requests MODIFY COLUMN identifier DEFAULT '<give_default_value_according_to_your_need>'`.

Answer (score 0):

Nextauth verification_request "identifier" refers to user e-mail address passed from the login form. The error usually means that you are not passing email parameter to /api/auth/signin/email/ in your POST request body.